# C++ Multiple Inheritance : Function Mismatch?

Tags: c++, inheritance

C++ won't allow me to construct an object of type `SymIntPoly` and call `f()` on it. Below are the classes and the structure.

```
template<typename T>
struct SymPoly
{
    T f() { return this->x; }
};

struct IntPoly
{
    int x;
    virtual int f() = 0;
};

struct SymIntPoly : public IntPoly, public SymPoly<int>
{
};
```

I do not know about compilers, but I feel that the compiler does not treat the two functions as the same functions (ie. they do not have the same internal signature?)

What is another way of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Which one did you expect to be called? In addition, `SymPoly` does not have `x` and `IntPoly` is abstract.

Comment: You have to define `f` in `SymIntPoly` or the class will remain abstract and you will not ever be able to instantiate it. Once you will have define `f` in it, there will be no ambiguity on the call to `f()`.

Comment: One problem is that  `return this->x;` in the template class makes no sense. It's difficult to know *why* you want to do this. But you could be stumbling on the CRTP pattern. Do Google that.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you want, but maybe try defining f within SymIntPoly as `int f() { return SymPoly<int>::f(); }`?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a lot of that poor compiler. The situation could become very ambiguous if it started allowing thins kind of things.

Fortunately, it's not difficult to help it figure out what you want. Try something like

```
template<typename T>
struct SymPoly
{
    virtual T getX() =0;
    T f() { return getX(); }
};

struct IntPoly
{
    int x;
    virtual int f() = 0;
};

struct SymIntPoly : public IntPoly, public SymPoly<int>
{
    int getX() { return IntPoly::x; }
    int f() { return SymPoly<int>::f(); }
};
```

This compiles.